# How do I make NuxtLink ignore css animation?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have page with background-color animated. I'm trying to navigate to another page using NuxtLink, but it doesn't render another page until css animation on the current page finishes. Is there a way for a NuxtLink to ignore animations?

Page with animation

```
<template>
  <div class="animated">
    <h1>MAIN</h1>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "IndexPage",
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.animated {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: anim;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }

  to {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
</style>
```

Layout with NuxtLinks

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <NuxtLink to="/">Main</NuxtLink>
      <NuxtLink to="/foo">Foo</NuxtLink>
      <NuxtLink to="/bar">Bar</NuxtLink>
    </nav>
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

Another page without animation

```
<template>
  <h1>FOO</h1>
</template>
```

When I try to navigate from Main to Foo page, it transitions only after animation in main finishes. I would like it to transition to another page regardless of css.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-kate-k4t77r

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by wrapping the animated page inside a div. It might be colliding with nuxt transitions, I'm not sure but now it works.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="animated">
      <h1>MAIN</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```